# New local user can't login to vsftpd

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I'm a bit puzzled with this one and could really use some help.

We have a CentOS 6 box running VSFTPD as a dropbox for our customers.  Each customer gets a local user and is chrooted to their home dir.  Connections are made with explicit SSL.

VSFTPD config as follows:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
check_shell=NO
```

So far we have added 3 users, each in the same way.

```
useradd -s /sbin/nologin username
passwd username
```

The first 2 users work perfectly.  The 3rd gets a `Login Incorrect` message from VSFTPD.

I've change the 3rd users password to `test` just to check there wasn't a typo in the connection but get the same thing.

Message in `/var/log/secure` for the 3rd user attempt is

```
pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=user3 rhost=127.0.0.1  user=user3
```

Anyone have any suggestions.

#### EDIT: In response to comments

The SELinux status is disabled

The output from `ls -lZd` in each directory is

Working user:
`drwx------ user1 user1 ?                                .`

Non-working user:
`drwxr-xr-x user2 user2 ?                                .`

So there is an obvious difference in permissions, but the working user is *less* permissive?

Comment: can you provoke an authentication failure with another user by entering a wrong password? Are they also known as uid=0 euid=0?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk done as asked. Exactly the same output in the secure log when using incorrect password for one of the other users. They are known as uid=0 euid=0

Comment: strange to me but this also means the problem is somewhere different

Comment: Things to scrutinize: (1) home dir. perms (2) .ssh perms. (3) user's have home dirs. defined in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: What is your SElinux status? Could you provide a `ls -lZd /home/user_that_works` and `ls -lZd /home/user_that_dont_works`?

Comment: @ludiegu updated question with what you've asked for.

Comment: @slm as per my update the perms *are* different on user dirs but not in a way i can see affecting this. will try changing.  .ssh perms are ok, but should have an affect as this is not an ssh ftp, just an ftp with ssl.  users all have correct home dirs in /etc/passwd

Comment: I had the same problem. My /etc/shells didn't contain the /bin/bash shell which the user has been set to use. Strange thing is I was able to connect with the same user through ssh ! I was used to think this thing should prevent a user from connecting even through ssh.

Comment: Do you use a 'whitelist' for the users? When using chrooted dirs in vstfpd you need to specify a file that holds the usernames allowed to use the service.
I don't know if CentOs follows the same setup, but on Ubuntu it is located at `/etc/vsftp.user_list` and holds all allowed usernames on newlines

Answer (score 4):

PAM won’t let you authorise the user if their shell isn’t listed in `/etc/shells`.

Change the user shell to a correct `nologin`:

```
# chsh -s $(command -v nologin) user3
```

And make sure it is listed in `/etc/shells`:

```
# grep "$(command -v nologin)" /etc/shells || echo "$(command -v nologin)" >> /etc/shells
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that you used 
**useradd**

not **adduser**

sudo adduser username

Please check this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2240340

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as per the tags this is CentOS where the command is `useradd` ;) but good to know that when I get round to trying Ubuntu it's `adduser`

Comment: This was the issue for me, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take care you have created the user with /sbin/nologin 
because a typo error like /bin/nologin makes the difference